# Vertical toolbar in Firefox Quantum 68.4.1esr?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

After the move to Web Extensions, the **Vertical Toolbars** add-on stopped working.

Noone has bothered to make a WE version.  Is this because it can't be done?

I really miss **Vertical Toolbars**, **All-in-One Sidebar**, and **Custom Buttons**.  I had my FireFox browser so tricked out that I hardly had to think:

[Screenshot of my set-up on 2018-04-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk8Q3.jpg)

Thanks!
   ~ SoSaysSunny

Comment: I couldn't find an extension to do so but there is a reddit post which discusses doing it with `userChrome.css`: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/97qi4s/vertical_bookmarks_addon_alternative_to_vertical/